# To Switch To The Design View Of A Windows Form

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I create new project in Windows Form Application using Visual Studio in VB.Net.
I place some controls on my form.
I don't write any code at this time.
I close this project.
When i open this project again , i found Form1.vb.
I double-click that file , but the design view doesn't appear.
I also find Form1.Designer.vb.
What in this file is code.
How can i switch to Design View of Form1 ?
I need to write some codes for that form's objects like Button Click Event.

June

Answer (score 0):

Use F7 button to toggle between Design View and Code View.

Comment: Firstly , I wanna thank you for your reply. When i press F7 , i still can't find the design view of my form. But when i run that application , i can see my form. I just can't see my form in design view. Actually when I Double-Click on the file Form1.vb or when I Right-Click in Form1.Designer.vb and choose View Designer or when i press F7 , i should see the form in design view. But I don't find it.

Comment: In Form1.Designer.vb , in the drop-down list box , it should be Form1.But i just saw General. Form1 doesn't appear at the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

You should not edit Form1.Designer.vb file. And be sure there is at least the following lines exist.

```
Public Class Form1

End Class
```

Tun Zarni Kyaw

Answer (score 0):

(Here, I am taking your Form as f1)

To view the design, just go like - View>Solution Explorer>f1 (double click on f1 to open its design).

Answer (score 0):

Click the button in Solution Explorer - Folder View to "Switch between solutions and available views" and then click on the form file.

Answer (score 0):

F7 to toggle from design mode to code
Shift + F7 to toggle back to design mode

Answer (score -1):

I realized the issue appears (at least for me) when there are multiple classes defined inside the .vb file.

To solve the issue you have to make sure the Form class is the first (right after the imports).
Move any other class definition below this class and forms designer will become available again.